# Is there any way to replace dynamic methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermock

Let's say we have an interface which has two methods:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    public SomeType first();
    public SomeType second();
}
```

This interface is implemented by `MyInterfaceImpl`. Inside the implementation, `first()` calls `second()` to retrieve some results.

I want to build a unit test which would assert things coming out of `first()` based on what comes out of `second()`, similar to:

```
1  public class MyInterfaceTest {
2     private MyInterface impl = new MyInterfaceImpl();

4     @Test
5     public void testFirst() {
6         // modify behaviour of .second()
7         impl.first();
8         assertSomething(...);

10        // modify behaviour of .second()
11        impl.first();
12        assertSomethingElse(...);
13    }
14 }
```

Is there an easy way to create a mock on the line `2` so that all calls to selected methods (e.g. `first()`) would be invoked directly (delegated to `MyInterfaceImpl`) whereas some other methods (e.g. `second()`) replaced with mock counterparts?

This is actually very easily doable with PowerMock for static methods, but I need something similar for dynamic ones.

Solutions based on

```
MyInterface mock = EasyMock.createMock(MyInterface.class);
MyInterface real = new MyInterfaceImpl();
EasyMock.expect(mock.first()).andReturn(real.first()).anyTimes();
EasyMock.expect(mock.second()).andReturn(_somethingCustom_).anyTimes();
```

are not good enough, especially for interfaces having lots of methods (lots of boilerplate). I need the forwarding behaviour as `real` actually depends on other mocks.

I would expect something like this to be handled by a framework, and not by my own class. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about good old subclassing? I mean something like

```
private MyInterface impl = new MyInterfaceImpl(){
    public final MyInterface mock = EasyMock.createMock(MyInterface.class);
    @override //only the method you need to mock
    public SomeType second(){
        return mock.second();        
    }
}

@Test
public void testFirst() {
    // modify behaviour of .second()
    EasyMock.expect(impl.mock.second()).andReturn("What I want").anyTimes();
    impl.first();
    assertSomething(...);

    // modify behaviour of .second()
    EasyMock.expect(impl.mock.second()).andReturn("Now I want something else").anyTimes();
    impl.first();
    assertSomethingElse(...);
}
```

You are not testing the exact class you want to test, but an anonymous subclass. But we can assume subclassing works ok in Java.;-)

Comment: I have actually implemented something along these lines. Will accept this answer as I don't think EasyMock can do what I wanted anyway :(

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should quite possibly have separate interfaces for `first()` and `second()`, if the implementation of `first()` has to call `second()`. You could then split the implementation too, and mock out `second()` while testing `first()`. Without a more concrete example of what `first()` and `second()` are, it's tricky to say for sure.

Using EasyMock on the implementation class to mock out *only* `second()` call *might* work, but you don't seem to want to do that anyway. This *may* require telling EasyMock to pass calls to `first()` through to the normal implementation - I'm not sure.

Another option might be to subclass the implementation within the test class (as a nested class) allowing you to override just `second()` for the purposes of testing. It's pretty ugly though.

Personally I don't like faking out *part* of a class just to test the rest. I'd much rather fake out *all* a class's dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately, splitting first() and second() is not an option - our design is centric to business logic type, and the idea is to keep all the functions that do work for that type of work under the same roof. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @mindas: I'd encourage you to at least revisit that decision. An account authenticator shouldn't be the same type as an account report generator, for example. If you're bound by ugly design decisions, you shouldn't be surprised when the testing (and implementation) become ugly too :( (That's assuming it really *is* an ugly design, of course. I'm speculating, but it sounds like it...)

Comment: This gets a bit offtopic, but are you really suggesting  methods shouldn't be using other public methods of the same class? E.g. in Java String.equalsIgnoreCase calls String.regionMatches - and although these are different functions, they are not _that_ different to be placed separately. Maybe it's a bad example in the sense that String is not an interface but what I wanted point out that my case is quite similar so first() and second() do a very close thing.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could use a [Dynamic Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html).

Comment: Very interesting advice. However it isn't applicable here - when inside first(), second() is called based on `this` which cannot be faked/proxied (unless MyImpl would call second() dynamically which doesn't make sense). But thanks for suggestion anyway, because of it I now have learned some fun stuff about dynamic proxies :)